# Case sensitivity in Power BI

Tags: oracle, powerbi, case-sensitive

I wanted to know if it's possible to configure the case sensitivity in Power BI. I have data in an Oracle DB where a primary key `EXample` is different from `exampLE`. But if I want to import it in Power BI, it won't work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

For now, I think your best bet would be to create an index for your primary key in the query editor stage and then use that index in Power BI for your relationships.

This is outlined here:

http://www.thebiccountant.com/2015/08/17/create-a-dimension-table-with-power-query-avoid-the-bug/

You can also vote for case sensitivity to be configurable here:

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/17235656-case-sensitive-insensitive-option

Comment: The link for the ideas page is no longer valid.