# Power BI case insensitive with JSON

Tags: json, azure, powerbi

I'm connecting to Azure resources via API at resources.azure.com, from there I'm taking the API for Microsoft.Compute and importing all the VM details into Power BI via JSON.

The import works fine, however with some situations of the data there is case discrepancy. For example, when working with the tags value, some people have typed the same word but in different case, such as;

```
    "tags": {
      "Project": "DT",
      "SLStandard": "Yes"
```

compared to

```
    "tags": {
      "project": "DT",
      "SlStandard": "Yes"
```

When expanding the columns out in Power BI it will consider the items listed above as two different value.

[image: Power BI case sensitivity]

Ideally I would like to have the JSON imported and the 'case' ignored, or perhaps mark all incoming as either upper or lower case.

I have read the two links below, but I'm new to Power BI and I'm unsure how to implement it, or even if it is what I need.

[Case sensitivity in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830288/case-sensitivity-in-power-bi)
and 
[Power BI changing text case automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529277/power-bi-changing-text-case-automatically)
and 
http://www.thebiccountant.com/2016/10/27/tame-case-sensitivity-power-query-powerbi/

Here is my Advanced Editor code:

```
let
    iterations = 10,
    url = 
     "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/< subscription id >/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2017-12-01",

    FnGetOnePage =
     (url) as record =>
      let
       Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url)),
       data = try Source[value] otherwise null,
       next = try Source[nextLink] otherwise null,
       res = [Data=data, Next=next]
      in
       res,

    GeneratedList =
     List.Generate(
      ()=>[i=0, res = FnGetOnePage(url)],
      each [i]<iterations and [res][Data]<>null,
      each [i=[i]+1, res = FnGetOnePage([res][Next])],
      each [res][Data]),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(GeneratedList, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1"),
    #"Expanded Column2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column1", {"tags"}, {"Column1.tags"}),
    #"Expanded Column1.tags" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column2", "Column1.tags", {"Project", "project", "SLStandard", "sLStandard", "BIOffline", "bIStandard", "AutomationBI", "biStandard", "BIStandard", "asdf-U001", "TestVM"}, {"Column1.tags.Project.1", "Column1.tags.project", "Column1.tags.SLStandard.1", "Column1.tags.sLStandard", "Column1.tags.BIOffline", "Column1.tags.bIStandard.1", "Column1.tags.AutomationBI", "Column1.tags.biStandard.2", "Column1.tags.BIStandard", "Column1.tags.asdf-U001", "Column1.tags.TestVM"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1.tags"
```

If you're wondering about why my query is so long for import, then check out my previous post here: [Power BI - Call Azure API with nextLink (next page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771173/power-bi-call-azure-api-with-nextlink-next-page)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this answered on another forum and tried it, and it does work.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-case-insensitive-with-JSON/m-p/360134

"You can rename your record fields (by applying Text.Proper for example) before expanding (in the last step):"

```
Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Column2", {{"tags", each Record.RenameFields(_, List.Zip({Record.FieldNames(_), List.Transform(Record.FieldNames(_), (name)=> Text.Proper(name))}))}}),
```

An the final output looks like this:

```
let
    iterations = 10,
    url = 
     "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/< subscription >/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2017-12-01",

FnGetOnePage =
 (url) as record =>
  let
   Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url)),
   data = try Source[value] otherwise null,
   next = try Source[nextLink] otherwise null,
   res = [Data=data, Next=next]
  in
   res,

GeneratedList =
 List.Generate(
  ()=>[i=0, res = FnGetOnePage(url)],
  each [i]<iterations and [res][Data]<>null,
  each [i=[i]+1, res = FnGetOnePage([res][Next])],
  each [res][Data]),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(GeneratedList, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1"),
#"Expanded Column2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column1", {"properties", "tags"}, {"properties", "tags"}),
#"Expanded properties" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Column2", {{"tags", each Record.RenameFields(_, List.Zip({Record.FieldNames(_), List.Transform(Record.FieldNames(_), (name)=> Text.Proper(name))}))}}),
#"Expanded properties1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded properties", "properties", {"vmId"}, {"properties.vmId"}),
#"Expanded tags" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded properties1", "tags", {"Project", "Slstandard", "Bioffline", "Bistandard", "Automationbi", "asdf-U001", "Testvm"}, {"tags.Project", "tags.Slstandard", "tags.Bioffline", "tags.Bistandard", "tags.Automationbi", "tags.asdf-U001", "tags.Testvm"})
in
#"Expanded tags"
```

Hope this helps other people!

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with the same issue today.  One workaround, although not elegant, is to lowercase or UPPERCASE the JSON upstream.

Worked for me as a temporary solution.

Hope it helps,
Chris

Comment: @Chris W, this is doing my head in. If you are able to find another work around, then I'm all ears. Sadly I cannot find a way to change the incoming JSON when it comes straight from Azure API, but I'll keep that in mind and see if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue is coming directly from the data source and the discrepancy between the field names at the data source level.

Here's a sample code on how you can force/make sure that they all have the same casing:

```
let
  Source = {[A=24,b=53], [a=43,B=43], [a=3,b=3]},
  Custom1 = List.Transform(Source, (_)=> Record.RenameFields(_, List.Zip({Record.FieldNames(_), List.Transform(Record.FieldNames(_), Text.Lower)})))
```

Comment: I've had a crack at implementing this into my existing code, but sadly my feeble brain cannot work it out :-/